# Lightning App keeps reloading due to URL conflict

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, coveo

I just created a lightning component that calls a server side apex class to generate a token in order to query an external service and show search results.
When I load the component using the app preview from the developer console, everything works fine, however, when I use the component in a lightning app and load it from a lightning app home page, it starts loading indefinitely, and a quick side note, this would not be appreciated by someone who suffers from epilepsy.

My main component loads the scripts from my static resources, then I call the controller function afterScriptsLoaded along with its helper. Any Idea why this might be happening?

app.cmp

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" controller="ApexTestWrapper" >
<ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.Namespace__Script1 + '/css/someCss.css'}"
 scripts="{!join(',',
          $Resource.Namespace__Script2+ '/js/SomeJs.min.js',
        $Resource.Namespace__Script3+ '/js/MoreJs.Dependencies.js',
        $Resource.Namespace__Script4+ '/js/templates/templatesNew.js')}"

 afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.load}"/>

  <body id="search" class='SearchInterface' data-enable-history="true" data-design="new">
      <div class="tab-section">
... More html
  </body>
</aura:component>
```

appcontroller.js

```
({
load : function(component, event, helper) {

        // getToken is the name of the Apex method that will be executed.
        var action = component.get('c.getToken');
        // The response will contain the token.
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            if(response.getState() == 'SUCCESS') {
                 var searchToken = response.getReturnValue();
                 helper.success(searchToken)
            }
        })
        // Queue the action using the framework available methods.
        $A.enqueueAction(action); 
    }
})
```

apphelper.js

```
({
success : function(searchToken) {
      ConnectTo.SearchEndpoint.endpoints['default'] = new The.SearchEndpoint({
        restUri: 'https://searchUri/rest/search',
         accessToken: searchToken
          
       });
    var theElement = document.getElementById("search");  
        Framework.init(theElement);
}
})
```

I also noted the following, when I do load the app (then the horrible reloading blinking starts), and then click on Home, my app loads, the tab doesn't change to the home page and everything suddenly is fine...(until I reload the page and the experience repeats itself)

[image]

occasionally, while switching tabs, the home tab will stick no matter what until i reload the page:
[image]

I am under the impression that this has something to do with the both frameworks (lightning and the one I am using) trying to append data to the URL , since when I switch subtabs in my app, it does a query and adds

> ## t=Case&sort=relevancy

to the URL, while the lightning framework tries to add something like this:

> a:t=1490311116404

when I click a subtab this is my url:
[image]

How could I resolve this and avoid this horrible light show.

Thanks!

fyi: the framework I am using is available here: https://github.com/coveo/search-ui

Comment: why don't you use the standard lightning component navigation: [force:navigateToURL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_navigateToURL.htm)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time I submitted a new query the fragment identifier (or hash) portion of the URL was being updated, in order to disable this, I had to set the CoveoSearchInterface enableHistory option to false:

```
      <body id="search" class='CoveoSearchInterface' data-enable-history="false" data-design="new">
```

as mentioned in the frameworks documentation [here](https://developers.coveo.com/display/public/JsSearchV1/Step+8+-+State+and+QueryStateModel+%3A+Interacting+With+Component+State+and+With+the+URL#Step8-StateandQueryStateModel:InteractingWithComponentStateandWiththeURL-URLasStateRepresentation)